# Are 9 again, 8 again, etc cumulative or stacking?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

While reading through things for the first werewolf game in ages (2nd edition nwod) I saw that there is a gift that gives rahu 8 again on brawl while there is a merit that can grant 9 again (or if 9 again is already there 8 again) on an auspice skill (which also can be brawl).

Thus I began to wonder if there is any stacking there or any enhanced bonus if you gain 8 again for something where you already have 9 again or 8 again)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There's no stacking

If you have 9 again on brawl and it's improved to 8 again. Then you have 8 again on brawl.

In order from best to worst:

- 8 again (reroll all dice which come up 8, 9 or 10)
- 9 again (reroll all dice which come up 9 or 10)
- 10 again (reroll all dice which come up 10)

[Some probabilities](http://anydice.com/articles/new-world-of-darkness/).